# sequelize cli not using postgres

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Running

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

prints out:

```
Sequelize [Node: 6.9.4, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.24.6]

Loaded configuration file "config\development.json".
Unable to connect to database: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Then having a look at config/development.json I see:

```
{
    "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "mydb",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "5432",
    "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "mydb",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "5432",
    "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "production": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "mydb",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "5432",
    "dialect": "postgres"
    }
}
```

Why? Why is sequelize still trying to go to mysql port?  ialso added the port as you can see in the config file. I could not find any resource saying postgres is not supported. But it seems sequelize-cli still doesn't care about the dialect or even the port number I entered in config-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `NODE_ENV` is different than `development`, `test` or `production`, because if it would match any of them, you would obtain a message like

```
Loaded configuration file "config/development.json".
Using environment "development".
Unable to connect to database: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

However, in your case it does not print which environment it uses, so it means it is none from your `development.json` file. You can try it with

```
sequelize db:migrate --env development
```

According to `sequelize-cli` source code, it gets the env variable with use of `getEnvironment` method which is like that:

```js
getEnvironment: function () {
    return args.env || process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
}
```

If you do not pass the `--env` argument, then it takes current `NODE_ENV`. It would mean that yours is different.